# I have an Accounts with multiple related Contacts. How can I retrieve only one Contract for each Account?

Tags: set, apex, soql

I have an Accounts with multiple related Contacts.
My requirement is to retrieve one contact record for each account. If one Account have multiple Contact I just want to retrieve one Contact record.

I created a list for Contact and Account however I'm not sure how can I only retrieve one related contact in each accounts.